# Debug output of keras layers during training

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

When fitting a model using keras, I encounter nans, and I want to debug the output of each layer.

The code has an input **in1** which goes through multiple layers, and during the final layer I multiply elementwise with another input **in2** and then do the prediction. The input **in2** is sparse and is used for masking (a row resembles something like this *[0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0... 0]*). Label matrix contains one-hot-encoded rows. Input **in1** is a vector of real values.

```
in1 = Input(shape=(27,), name='in1')
in2 = Input(shape=(1000,), name='in2')

# Hidden layers
hidden_1 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(in1)
hidden_2 = Dense(512, activation='relu')(hidden_1)
hidden_3 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(hidden_2)
hidden_4 = Dense(10, activation='linear')(hidden_3)

final = Dense(1000, activation='linear')(hidden_4)

# Ensure we do not overflow when we exponentiate
final2 = Lambda(lambda x: x - K.max(x))(final)

#Masked soft-max using Lambda and merge-multiplication
exponentiate = Lambda(lambda x: K.exp(x))(final2)

masked = Multiply()([exponentiate, in2])

predicted = Lambda(lambda x: x / K.sum(x))(masked)

# Compile with categorical crossentropy and adam
mdl = Model(inputs=[in1, in2],outputs=predicted)
mdl.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
            optimizer='adam',
            metrics=['accuracy'])
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="/Users/somepath/tmp/{}".format(time()), write_graph=True, 
                            write_grads=True)
mdl.fit({'in1': in1_matrix, 'in2': in2_matrix}, 
         label_matrix, epochs=1, batch_size=32, verbose=2, callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

I want to print the output of each layer, gradients during training and how to send auxiliary input (**in2**) while debugging.

I have tried to print the output of each layer like below, which works until layer7:

```
get_layer_output = K.function([mdl.layers[0].input],[mdl.layers[7].output])
layer_output = get_layer_output([in1_matrix])
```

But when I get to layer 8, I'm unable to add **in2_matrix**. I get the following error when I use the following code to print.

```
get_layer_output2 = K.function([mdl.layers[0].input],[mdl.layers[8].output])
layer_output2 = get_layer_output2([in1_matrix])
```

Error:

> InvalidArgumentError: You must feed value for placeholder tensor 'in2' with dtype float and shape [?,1000]

I don't know how to provide **in2** in *K.function*, and also **in2_matrix** to **get_layer_output2**.

(I have checked the **in1_matrix**, **in2_matrix**, and the **label_matrix**. They all look fine, with no nans or inf. Label array has no rows or columns with all zeros.)'

I'm new to Keras, any idea on how to debug nans, with callbacks even to print gradients would be appreciated. Please also let me know if there is anything wrong with the way the layers are composed.

Answer (score 0):

If you print out `mdl.layers[8]`, you can find it is Input layer, I guess you want to get the output of `mdl.layers[9]`, which is Multiply layer. You can get like this,

```py
get_layer_output2 = K.function([mdl.layers[0].input, mdl.layers[8].input],[mdl.layers[9].output])
layer_output2 = get_layer_output2([in1_matrix, in2_matrix])
```

Comment: You're welcome. If helped, accept or upvote are appreciated.